# Does my string full of various delimiters have a specific delimiter in use, but not in the data contained in the string?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string

If we have the new delimiter in place, I know not to use the old one.
If my string uses the "," for a delimiter I will continue to use it (and not allow it in data) but if it doesn't I want to use the new delimiter "!".

We have a string like 
“Web Distribution:Walnut Creek & State Specialty - At Home::1757:1-1-3~1:1-1-3~2:1-1-2~0-0~=~1~Yes, complete today while at store~0.b   Willing:::”

We are doing a test to see if it used ‘!’ as a delimiter string.Contains(“!”)

If it does then we are cool

If it doesn’t

We are testing to see if ‘,’ is used as a delimiter
We are doing a simple test of string.Contains(“,”)

This is where we have a problem.
“Yes, complete today while at store”

So how can I say, great it has a “,” but if it’s between two ~ don’t worry about it. Use the ! as the delimiter moving forward and let the “,” live in the question and alert plugin.

If the text looks like 
“Web Distribution:Walnut Creek & State Specialty - At Home::1757:1-1-3~1:1-1-3~2:1-1-2~0-0~=~1~Yes, complete today while at store~0.b   Willing^1-1-2~0-0~=~2~Yes, complete later via email~0.b   Willing::1-1-2~0-0~=~0~~0.b - Willing!1-1-3~0-0~=~0~~0.c - Email:”

It has a “!” and we are cool

my current code

```
Friend Const mcItemDelimiterOld As String = ","
Friend Const mcItemDelimiterNew As String = "!"
Public Shared mcItemDelimiter As String = "!"

    If sDelimitedText.Contains(mcItemDelimiterNew) Then
        mcItemDelimiter = mcItemDelimiterNew
    Else
        If sDelimitedText.Contains(mcItemDelimiterOld) Then
            mcItemDelimiter = mcItemDelimiterOld
        Else
            mcItemDelimiter = mcItemDelimiterNew
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Could you clarify what output you need if the input is `Web Distribution:Walnut Creek & State Specialty - At Home::1757:1-1-3~1:1-1-3~2:1-1-2~0-0~=~1~Yes, complete today while at store~0.b Willing^1-1-2~0-0~=~2~Yes, complete later via email~0.b Willing::1-1-2~0-0~=~0~~0.b - Willing!1-1-3~0-0~=~0~~0.c - Email:`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I need to know if the delimiter is in use, but not in the any of the data of the string. In the value you have in your comment it has an '!' and that can't be in any of the rest of the sting, so I know to use '!' for the rest of the process. If it doesn't have a '!' or ',' I use a '!'.